# How to solve "N+1" problem in Keystone.js

Tags: query-optimization, keystonejs

It seems, that Keystone.js does't provides a solution of "N+1" problem.
Maybe, they are some plugins for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/cache-hints/

This is a typical pattern for solving this problem.

You can try:

```
const app = new GraphQLApp({
  apollo: {
    cacheControl: {
      defaultMaxAge: 3600,
    },
  },
});
```

to cache all resolver results.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you on? The current version of KeystoneJS ([Keystone Next](https://next.keystonejs.com)) is build on top of [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) which should be building fairly performant DB queries. If there's a specific GraphQL query you're preforming that's resulting in a suboptimal SQL it may represent a bug in either Keystone or Prisma code, in which case it'd be great if you could isolate the problem and [log an issue](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues).

If you're adding hooks, access control or virtual fields that query the DB it is possible to encounter the N+1 problem as those functions can be called for each item returned in a query. For example, this code, taken from the [`virtual-fields` example](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/examples/virtual-field/schema.ts) causes N+1 queries if used as written:

```js
Post: list({
  fields: {
    // [... various fields ...]

    author: relationship({ ref: 'Author.posts', many: false }),

    // A virtual field which uses `item` and `context` to query data.
    authorName: virtual({
      field: schema.field({
        type: schema.String,
        async resolve(item, args, context) {
          const { author } = await context.lists.Post.findOne({
            where: { id: item.id },
            query: 'author { name }',
          });
          return author && author.name;
        },
      }),
    }),
  },
}),
```

Here, the resolver function for the `authorName` field will be called for each item loaded (assuming the field is queried). In these cases I'd suggest using something like the [GraphQL dataloader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader) (or similar) over the top of the Keystone CRUD API. If used correctly, dataloader can combine multiple queries and resolve the N+1 behaviour.